# the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s)

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Getting that error in Keras. 
Scenario: 
Input:

1. Images with train shape as (50000, 32, 32, 3)
2. Aux input with shape (50000, 1)
3. Ground truth: (50000, 1)

This is model fit code

```
x_train_input = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

aux_rand_input = Input(shape=(1,))

out = model_inst.build_model(x_train_input, aux_rand_input)

model = Model(inputs=[x_train_input, aux_rand_input], outputs=[out])

model.fit(x=[x_train, aux_input], y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size, epochs=maxepoches, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard], verbose=2)
```

Got this error when running this.

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are
>   passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to
>   see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

And this is how `build_model`'s last few layers look like.

```
    flatten = Flatten()(drop_5)
    # aux_input = Input(shape=(1,))
    concat = Concatenate(axis=1)([flatten, aux_input])

    fc1 = Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay))(concat)
    fc1 = Activation('relu')(fc1)
    fc1 = BatchNormalization()(fc1)

    fc1_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc1)
    fc2 = Dense(self.num_classes)(fc1_drop)
    out = Activation('softmax')(fc2)
    return out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For validation data you are passing only one array for inputs.

```
model.fit(x=[x_train, aux_input], y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size, epochs=maxepoches, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard], verbose=2)
```

You should pass values for both `aux_rand_input` and `x_train_input`. If you have `aux_test` variable to hold test data for `aux_rand_input`, then this can be done as follows

```
model.fit(x=[x_train, aux_input], y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size, epochs=maxepoches, validation_data=([x_test, aux_test], y_test), callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard], verbose=2)
```

#### Edit:

To use the `model.fit_generator` method the generator must yield tuple or list of two elements with the first element consisting two arrays. E.g.

```
def generator(x, aux, y):
   ## part of the code...
   yield [batch_x, batch_aux], batch_y
```

Comment: Juts an out of context question - how can I do the same using model.fit_generator?